# $(P\implies Q) \implies [(R ∨ P)\implies (R ∨ Q)]$ is a tautology

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm currently trying to work on the proof for this tautology.
But every time I derive the right side, I end up with a lone $R$ that will never cancel out.

Like I always end up with

$$(P\implies Q) \implies  ¬P∨Q∨R$$

And the $R$ never goes away at this point.

What can I do to cancel out the $R$?

Comment: Try to get to a point where you have $P\vee\lnot P\vee (\dots)$ or $Q\vee\lnot Q\vee (\dots)$

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much I got it from trying to get this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with the [method of analytic tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux), described in detail in M D’Agostino's *Handbook of Tableaux Methods*. This approach is somewhat informal but what it produces is often very suggestive of a proof (and is even equivalent to one in many semantics).

We start with the negation of $$(P\to Q)\to ((R\vee P)\to (R\vee Q))\tag{1}$$ then apply a series of contradiction-hunting rules to show that the negation is always false. Look:

[image].

This ends in contradictions. Thus $(1)$ is indeed a tautology.

I hope that helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: The code for the diagram above can be found [here](https://www.writelatex.com/709765tmjvvg#/1522225/).

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** $(P\to Q)\to\lnot P\lor Q\lor R\equiv(P\to Q)\to((P\to Q)\lor R)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can take benefit of the fact that :

> $(A \implies B)$ is equivalent to $(\lnot A \lor B)$

so that, e.g

> $(R \lor P)$ will be $(\lnot R \implies P)$.

Now, if you rewrite your formula in this way, you will get :

> $$(P \implies Q) \implies [ (\lnot R \implies P) \implies (\lnot R \implies Q)]$$

and this is a version of *Hypothetical Syllogism*.

Answer (score 2):

```
P   Q   R   (P-->Q)   (R V P)  (R V Q)  [(R V P) --> (R V Q)] {(P-->Q) ->[(R V P)-->(R V Q)]}

T   T   T     T          T        T               T                     T

T   T   F     T          T        T               T                     T

T   F   T     F          T        T               T                     T

T   F   F     F          T        F               F                     T

F   T   T     T          T        T               T                     T

F   T   F     T          F        T               T                     T

F   F   T     T          T        T               T                     T

F   F   F     T          F        F               T                     T
```

The last column as all the T's which means your statement is a tautology. This is probably easier to do than use equivalent statements.

Comment: I have to agree with you that truth tables are a lot easier for tautology verification.

Comment: @usukidoll: That's totally not true. Look at my hint. Either $P\to Q$ is false, then the entire implication is true, or it's true and the entire implication is true. How is that not much simpler than a long table?

Comment: @usukidoll - Truth-tables are usuful for checking that your expected result (e.g.an *equivalence* or a *tautology*) is correct, provided the formula does not contain more than 3 or 4 literal. But you cannot use them to *prove*...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that's true because the truth tables become meaningless afterwards. It's only useful for very few logic problems. The rest deal with the definitions, propositions,  and set properties.

Comment: This is in need of formatting, but having tried to edit it myself, I think you've done a good job to keep the top all in one line :)

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straightforward with natural deduction:

- 1.  Suppose $P \to Q$.

  - 2. Suppose $R \lor P$.

    - 3. Suppose $R$.

      - 4. $R \lor Q$ by $\lor$-introduction with 3.
    - 5. Suppose $P$.

      - 6. $Q$ by $\to$-elimination with 1 and 5.
      - 7. $R \lor Q$ by $\lor$-introduction with 6.
    - 8. $R \lor Q$ by $\lor$-elimination with 2, 3–4, and 5–7.
  - 9. $(R \lor P) \to (R \lor Q)$ by $\to$-introduction with 2–8.
- 10. $(P \to Q) \to ((R\lor P) \to (R \lor Q))$ by $\to$-introduction with 1–9.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $P$ implies $Q$. This means that either (i) $P$ is false (and we don't care about $Q$) or (ii) $P$ is true and $Q$ true. In either case, we don't care about $R$; it's a red herring. So in case (i), $P$ is false, so that $\neg P\lor Q\lor R$  is true. In case (ii), $Q$ is true (and so is $P$, but we don't really care in this case), so that $\neg P\lor Q\lor R$ is true, again.

To sum up, ($P\Longrightarrow Q$) logically implies $\neg P\lor Q\lor R$.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a proof using natural deduction in a Fitch-style proof checker. The proof is similar to what Joshua Taylor provided.

[image]

The inference rules used are [disjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) ($\lor$I), [disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) ($\lor$E), [implication introduction or conditional proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) ($\to$I) and [implication elimination or modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) ($\to$E).

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/